# Creating PDF of Javadoc from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pdf, javadoc

I have been able to generate the javadoc for a project of mine, but I want to integrate it into my report.  Right now I just have a folder full of HTML documents, is there an easy way to turn these into a single pdf document or a way to generate the pdf document straight from eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [HTMLDOC](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) project. It generates PDF from HTML pages maintaining working hyperlinks.

You can use it from command line:

```
htmldoc --webpage -f pdf-file.pdf html-file-1.html ... html-file-N.html
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using a doclet on Maven-javadoc-plugin.

Basically just need to download the jar:

http://pdfdoclet.sourceforge.net/

And then add the plugin on your pom.xml as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>PDF</id>
                    <reports>
                        <report>javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>PDF</name>
                        <description>This is my Documentation on PDF.</description>
                        <destDir>pdf</destDir>
                        <doclet>com.tarsec.javadoc.pdfdoclet.PDFDoclet</doclet>
                        <docletPath>${basedir}\..\..\tools\pdfdoclet-1.0.3-all.jar</docletPath>
                        <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                        <additionalparam>
                            -pdf javadoc.pdf
                        </additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save files as a PDF inside eclipse. File -> Print -> and then one the popup window there is a select box that should say "PDF". If you click on that, one of the options is to save as PDF. Although, Eclipse adds formatting.